# TF is broken when using robot_localization package with only IMU sensor, how to assure that the measured velocity is the one from the robot?

Tags: ros, imu, transforms

Im using this[robot_lokalization](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/state_estimation_nodes.html) robot_localization package for the linear velocity. As only sensor input in my case is IMU. I configure the parameters and set the frames as follow

```
map_frame: map             
odom_frame: odom         
base_link_frame: /thrbot/base_link 
world_frame: odom
```

The launch file is the following one

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_se" clear_params="true">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find robot_localization)/params/ekf_template.yaml" />
    <param name="odom_used" value="false"/>
  </node>

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_imu" args="0 0 0 0 0 0  /thrbot/base_link /thrbot/imu_link  100" />

</launch>
```

The robot base_link frame is `thrbot/base_link` the IMU is `thrbot/imu_link`

Here is the photo of the TF without using the package[image: Normal TF of the Robot and the world] . But when using the package my TF is broken as can see from the photo here [image: broken TF]. Any help how to fix the TF and correctly use the package with IMU as only sensor input?

To fix the TF i change the configure the parameters in `ekf_template.yaml` as follow

```
odom_frame: odom          
base_link_frame: /thrbot/base_footprint  
world_frame: odom
```

and the launch file to follow

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_se" clear_params="true">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find robot_localization)/params/ekf_template.yaml" />
    <param name="frame_id" value="odom"/>
  </node>

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_odom" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /odom /thrbot/base_footprint 100" />

</launch>
```

Now the TF looks good as can see [image: Fixed TF]. Than following parameters are configure in `ekf_template.yaml`:

```
imu0: /thrbot/imu
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              true, true, true,
              false, false, false,
              true,  true,  true,
              true,  true,  true]

imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true
imu0_nodelay: false
imu0_differential: false
imu0_relative: true
imu0_queue_size: 5
imu0_pose_rejection_threshold: 0.8                
imu0_twist_rejection_threshold: 0.8                
imu0_linear_acceleration_rejection_threshold: 0.8
```

My question is now as that correct configuration for underwater UUV to get linear velocity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your configuration, you are trying to create `map -> odom -> /thrbot/base_link`. But you do not have a map frame. Looking at your oroginal TF, you should instead create `world -> odom -> base_footprint`.

I think your configuration should be:

```
odom_frame: odom         
base_link_frame: /thrbot/base_footprint 
world_frame: world
```

**EDIT**: as pointed out,

```
world_frame: odom
```

Comment: Ok. So what should I put in map_frame: ? just leave it empty?

Comment: with `odom_frame: odom         
base_link_frame: /thrbot/base_footprint 
world_frame: world`  I got ERROR `Odometry message frame_id was world, expected map or odom` . I think in the launch file need to specify parent and child frame correctly. Is this static transform in the above launch file ok?  `  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_imu" args="0 0 0 0 0 0  /thrbot/base_link /thrbot/imu_link  100" />
`

Comment: also in the ekf_template.yaml Im not sure about odom parameters settings such as; `odom0: example/odom` . is that correct? what should i put in odom parameters?

Comment: ok. Fix the TF . I update the question with the new settings and launch file, but have several doubts. . How to be sure that everything is in local frame and how to assure that the velocity is the real velocity of the robot? ( i know there will be error regarding the integration and will accumulate with time) but I like to know that with the parameters settings Im estimation the velocity of the robot and not something else. Please can you help with that?

Comment: Since you do not have a map, you can leave the map_frame empty, or just skip that tag. You are correct, the world_frame should be odom. My bad!
In your example, you only have an IMU right? If so, you should not populate odom0.

Comment: > how to assure that the velocity is the real velocity of the robot?

You will need some ground truth for comparison. How did you know that your IMU integrations had error? You will need some source of velocity to compare

Comment: yes I only have IMU. I have some  ideal ( covariance is 0) POSE 3D Sensor from the Simulation (but in my robot will not gonna use that sensor). So can compare with that. so not populate odom0 means what? is this settings correct: `odom0: /odom`  `odom0_config: [false,  false, false, false, false, false,false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]` . How not populate `odom0` ?

Comment: and the imu0 parameters config ok?  such as imu0_nodelay: false
imu0_differential: false
imu0_relative: true

Comment: You should really be renaming topics in the launch file to match naming in the params file. So if you use imu0 in the params file, remap imu0 to /your/imu_topic in the launch file. If you don't, the EKF will not get any input as it will be listening to imu0 topic. `<remap from="imu0" to="/your/imu_topic" />`

Comment: So if you want to ignore other sources (like odom) you can either **delete** those lines from the config (not set them to false, altough that might work!) or just don't rename them in your launch file. I'd recommend deleting them altogether

Comment: imu parameters would depend on your sensor and setup. Unfortunately no one can tell you what to use in your setup. I'd recommend reading through the wiki to see what those params do and/or get into the source code and figure out how to use them properly.

Comment: ok. thanks. will try

Comment: so my TF three is correct, right?

Comment: Ok, regarding IMU parameter Im not that worried as they can be tuned. My forst concerned is if my overall setting is correct. Means proper set up to use only IMU values and nothing else, than everything is in in local frame. So that my output make sense. After that i can work on IMU parameters tuning. Hope now more clear. Can you give me some feedback regarding the two first concerns ( overall set up of the node and yaml) and if everything  is in local frame? thanks

Comment: To know if the setup is right, you'd have to look at your entire setup. But yes, it seems like your tf issue is resolved and you are set to use just the IMU.

Comment: my main concern is that Velocity frame  is in the body frame. So the same as the robot

Comment: where and how to check that Velocity and the body frame are same?

Comment: and last question.  Is the  remap the input topics  robot_localization is expecting to the topics  my systems are outputting correct, such as  `<remap from="imu0" to="/thrbot/imu" />`

Comment: Yes, your remap seems correct